# How to copy data of one array to another in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memcpy

I have to copy Mac address stored as an array with a pointer reference to another. I want to perform a swap but, i dont know if i am copying right.

```
uint8_t * custom_mac_store;
memcpy(custom_mac_store, ehdr->ether_shost, sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost));
memcpy(ehdr->ether_shost, ehdr->ether_dhost, sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost));
memcpy(ehdr->ether_dhost, custom_mac_store, sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost));
```

ehdr->ether_shost refers to a Mac address which is 48 bits long and stored in 6 arrays as 8 bits.

```
struct sr_ethernet_hdr
{
#ifndef ETHER_ADDR_LEN
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN 6
#endif
    uint8_t  ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* destination ethernet address */
    uint8_t  ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];    /* source ethernet address */
    uint16_t ether_type;                     /* packet type ID */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) ;
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you checked the values before and after the copy? Print them out and compare!

Comment: Why don't you just run your code in debug mode and see?

Comment: Well for a start you will need to allocate some memory of appropriate size to `custom_mac_store`

Comment: To answer we should know the declarations of `ehdr->ether_shost` and `ehdr->ether_dhost`.

Comment: They do swap but they are part of a big buffer thats getting messed up. other values in that buffer are getting altered like IP address etc. @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @mathematician1975 Updated it

Comment: Regarding your comment:  _They do swap but they are part of a big buffer thats getting messed up_.  Make sure when you break the original string up, that you store each buffer with NULL termination.   `memcpy` does not do that for you like the string functions (i.e. `strcpy`, `strcat`, et. al.)

Comment: @ryyker: Which "string"?

Comment: OP refers to _a big buffer thats getting messed up_. You tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

custom_mac_store is a pointer, not an array, you should allocate the memory doing the following:

```
uint8_t * custom_mac_store = malloc(sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost) * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Then do the memcpy

This way you can erase or overwrite ehdr->ether_shost but you already copied your array to the new array.

@alk You are right you need to delete the memory

```
uint8_t * custom_mac_store = malloc(sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost) * sizeof(uint8_t));

memcpy(custom_mac_store, ehdr->ether_shost, sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost));
memcpy(ehdr->ether_shost, ehdr->ether_dhost, sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost));
memcpy(ehdr->ether_dhost, custom_mac_store, sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost));

free(custom_mac_store); //< Destroys everything in the array
custom_mac_store = NULL; //< NULL must be defined in a macro preferanly DEFINE NULL 0
```

or you could use c++

```
uint8_t * custom_mac_store = new uint8_t[sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost)];

std::copy ( ehdr->ether_shost, ehdr->ether_shost+sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost), custom_mac_store );
    std::copy ( ehdr->ether_dhost, ehdr->ether_dhost+sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost), ehdr->ether_shost );
    std::copy ( custom_mac_store, custom_mac_store+sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost), ehdr->ether_dhost );

delete[] custom_mac_store; //< Destroys everything in the array
```

or you could use the stack instead of the heap (this should be faster, just don't break the stack)

```
const std::size_t size_custom_mac_store = 48000;
uint8_t custom_mac_store[size_custom_mac_store]; //< The size must be either a const or a macro

std::copy ( ehdr->ether_shost, ehdr->ether_shost+sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost), custom_mac_store );
std::copy ( ehdr->ether_dhost, ehdr->ether_dhost+sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost), ehdr->ether_shost );
std::copy ( custom_mac_store, custom_mac_store+sizeof(ehdr->ether_shost), ehdr->ether_dhost );

delete[] custom_mac_store; //< Destroys everything in the array
```

Good luck.

PS: Love memory management, it's the only way

Comment: It works perfect now. Its not messing with other values in buffer

Comment: Why take the burdon doing this using dynamic allocation. Auto allocation on the stack should not be slower. Also you might forget to free it! See *SunEric*'s answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22020740/694576

Comment: Great news @user262644, it seemed like you knew what you were doing. Have a good one

Comment: @alk sure i will give that a try too. :)

Comment: @user262644 In c++ you use new and delete to handle memory, similar to java but in here you "have" to delete the memory when you deem necessary. In c you use malloc free. It is important not to mix both in the same code.

Answer (score 2):

You can define ethernet length as `6` then making use of a temporary array, just perform `memcpy` as below,

```
#define ETH_ALEN        6
uint8_t tmp[ETH_ALEN];
memcpy(tmp, eth->ether_shost, ETH_ALEN);
memcpy(eth->ether_shost, eth->ether_dhost, ETH_ALEN);
memcpy(eth->ether_dhost, tmp, ETH_ALEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

It might work if some memory was allocated for your temporary buffer `custom_mac_store`.
Like that it's just an uninitialized pointer waiting to cause a crash.
You can either allocate explicitly some memory to it, or use directly a 6 byte array instead.

Comment: which are the two solutions that popped up jut a few seconds before mine :-)